# error #1349 view's select clause contains a subquery in the from clause

Tags: sql, view, querying

Here is my code,

```
Select CAST.first_name, CAST.last_name, `directors winning movies list`.castID, count(*) AwardsWon
From `directors winning movies list`, CAST  
WHERE `directors winning movies list`.castID = CAST.castID
Group By `directors winning movies list`.castID
Having count(*)
    = (Select Max(cnt)
       From (Select count(*) cnt
             From `directors winning movies list`
             Group By `directors winning movies list`.castID) z)
```

The query itself executes correctly, but when I try and create a view and save this, I get the error #1349 view's select clause contains a subquery in the from clause. Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow to create a view with subquery.
The possible workaround would be to create separate view for each subquery.

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW movies_view AS
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
             FROM `directors winning movies list`
             GROUP BY `directors winning movies list`.castID) z)
```

---

```
CREATE VIEW movies_view_count AS
SELECT MAX(cnt) from movies_view
```

Call the `movies_view_count` in your main query and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by Call the movies_view_count in your main query and it should work? (I'm new to SQL :) )

Comment: Thank you I figured it out!!

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if you think it was helpful and fixed the error you were getting.